# Copy values from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

How can I copy some data from one worksheet to another?

I tried this code, but get an error:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Sheets("Gas Opt").Select
    Range("A1:A3").Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets("ExportToPPServer").Select
    Cells(3, AColumn).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    LFound = True
    MsgBox "Data coped."


End Sub
```

Error:

```
Select method of Range class failed.
```

Comment: Which line is producing the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this look?

```
Sub x()
    Sheets("Gas Opt").Select
    Range("A1:A3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ExportToPPServer").Range("A1:A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
End Sub
```

### Edit

Is your Control button on a different sheet than "Gas Opt"? That would explain it.  Try this:

```
Sub x()
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A3").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
End Sub
```

Comment: It jumps to the sheet I want to copy from and gives 'Select Method of range Class failed' error

Comment: Odd.  It works fine on my sheet. Perhaps because I'm doing it as a regular procedure and not as part of a control? idk.

Comment: Thanks. You edit worked. I guess I should have specified that the control button is on the destination sheet, not the source sheet.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim copyRng As Range, targetRng As Range

    Set copyRng = Worksheets("Gas Opt").Range("A1:A3")
    Set targetRng = Worksheets("ExportToPPServer").Cells(3, AColumn)

    copyRng.Copy 
    targetRng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    LFound = True
    MsgBox "Data coped."
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the sheet, else you cannot select cells in it.

```
Sheets("ExportToPPServer").Activate ' Instead of select
```

Comment: At range("A1:A3").Select, I get the same error as in my question.

Comment: That is probably because the sheet 'GasOpt' isn't active at that moment.